# Autohotkey - match a pattern in a string

Tags: regex, string, match, autohotkey

I need to figure out how to extract allo occurences of a pattern (eg: AAA | AAA) from a string like the one below:

```
InputString := "PGA|MGA v _ 914:00 x a: EDA|EFG v 7 913:42 x 5:: PFD|GRM"

RegexMatch(InputString, "([A-Z]{3})\|([A-Z]{3})", Match)

strMessage := "InputString = '" . InputString . "'"

strMessage .= "`nName = '" . Match1 . "'"

MsgBox, % strMessage
```

I tried this code but it 's clear that it isn't correct.

I also tried:

```
InputString := "PGA|MGA v _ 914:00 x a: EDA|EFG v 7 913:42 x 5:: PFD|GRM"

Pos:=RegExMatch( InputString, "g)([A-Z]{3})\|([A-Z]{3})", Match)

Msgbox % Match1
```

But nothing...maybe I'm doing something wrong in the syntax?

Comment: Please update your question's tags to show what language that's in. The format of a regex might (not likely, but still) depend on it.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I tried to put a tag like ahk or autohotkeys, but the system doesn't accept it.

Comment: Oh it's fine then. It looks like they support Perl regex format if anyone else is curious.

Comment: And what a weird language they use, see the `UnquotedOutputVar`: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link from the help documents [Global matching and Grep (forum link)](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/14817-grep-global-regular-expression-match/) on RegExMatch page.

I found this [page](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/51704-re-regexmatch-why-is-it-not-finding-all-the-subpatterns/) to be more helpful!

Try:

```
InputString := "PGA|MGA v _ 914:00 x a: EDA|EFG v 7 913:42 x 5:: PFD|GRM"

MsgBox % Format("Match #1 {1:}`nMatch #2 {2:}`nMatch #3 {3:}"
            , RegExMatchAll(InputString, "([A-Z]{3}[|][A-Z]{3})")*)

; Return Array of all Matches found!
RegExMatchAll(Input, Pattern, Pos=1) {
    matches := []
    While Pos := RegExMatch(Input, Pattern, m,Pos+StrLen(m))
       matches.push(m)
    return matches
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -- `g)([A-Z]{3}\|[A-Z]{3})`

The `g)` bit should set the regex matching option to 'global' so all matches are captured instead of just the first one.

From [AHK docs](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm#Parameters)

Comment: doesn't select anything?